# Should we be using gendered terminology to address the general population?

Tags: discussion, questions

I see questions all the time that are addressed to the "guys", like [JavaScript stopwatch saving in cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27867431/java-script-stopwatch-saving-in-cookies), which start with:

> So well, i need some help guys

Now, back in the day when I was young, many women would have protested such language. It still bothers me to see something like that. It makes me wonder, "so, you don't want help from females?"

But that was then, and this is now. My question is: are you not-guys offended and/or bothered by such language? Should I either correct it on your behalf, or at least comment to the OP?

---

Note that I'm not just talking about cases where "guys" is in a salutation. I'm also including "gentlemen" and other such words which suggest they might be directed only at males.

--

BTW, I used the term "NOT Guys" as a shortcut to indicate anyone who feels excluded by the term "Guys".

Comment: Obviously such content has no place in the post anyways, No comment on the question, since I am a guy.

Comment: "guys" can be (and commonly is) used informally to mean either sex.  Reference: https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=guys

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: sure, and when I'm removing other fluff, I try to remove that too. This question is about the fact that I'm offended on their behalf, and maybe that's no longer a necessary emotion.

Comment: I'd tend to edit out such irrelevant stuff. We're not gender concerned, and the text isn't relevant for the question at all.

Comment: @iCodez: just the sort of response I was hoping for - from the female readers. I'd like to hear whether _they_ feel it's an acceptable equivalent.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Well, I'm not female, but that's kind of _no brainer_ (my cutie female geckos would solve this well. Not I'm saying they don't have a brain, they well recognize a lot of things).

Comment: I'm a not-guy, and I say "guys" to groups of not-guys frequently. I don't speak for all not-guys, but I'd say the practice itself is relatively harmless. However it should be edited out of posts here simply because we don't use that kind of salutation, as has been noted above.

Comment: I'm also asking about cases where it's not part of a salutation. It happens that the first example I found was in a salutation.

Comment: @abbyhairboat I'm in the same (hair)boat, but I suppose the practice might be less harmless for non-native speakers who may not be familiar with the now-colloquial usage in the US/UK/wherever else this may be common.

Comment: Some text directed at "Gentlemen" would probably want to be edited out because it's a salutation and we don't use those here, *and* because it wrongly assumes that everyone here is a guy. "Guys" only falls in the first category, but it sorta doesn't matter, because it should get axed either way :)

Comment: @abbyhairboat _"Some text directed at "Gentlemen""_ Similarly as the frequent _Sirs_ coming up (primiarily from indian accounts as I've been noticing).

Comment: Anyone should feel free to add examples of the general problem. I only had time to find a single example, but of course there are many different types of this issue.

Comment: @JohnSaunders _"but of course there are many different types of this issue. "_ Edit out such irrelevant stuff, as soon you meet it, it's simple.

Comment: I mean that there are cases where a gender-specific word is used in text which would not otherwise be edited out.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - You have to realize too that there are more male programmers than female.   It is normal for people to assume they are talking to men when they post here.  Now, I'm not saying that this view is correct, but it is understandable and I'm certain that they do not mean any disrespect.  For example, you yourself responded to my previous comment as if I were a male even though I have never disclosed my gender. :)

Comment: @iCodez: I actually didn't assume you were male - I expected you to correct me if you were female. And my question isn't so much about reasonable assumptions on the part of the poster, as it is on how do the female readers _feel_ about the use of such language.

Comment: It is indeed awkward.  I hate referring to, say, OP's as 'it', but it's less typing than 'he/she'.

Comment: @MartinJames - I've seen people use "they" in that instance, but it can get a little confusing sometimes since "they" is plural.

Comment: for the futurama fans... why don't we just use shklee?

Comment: @JohnSaunders _"I expected you to correct me if you were female."_, Well, there might be even more kind of _genders_ to consider than just these two, to keep neutral nowadays. Anyway it's not relevant stuff for any valid questions or answers on SO.

Comment: Wow, really?-4?  I guess the answer to the question is "continue cleaning up all salutations, but for the rest, let the non-guys do it themselves".

Comment: As a quebec-guy (qualifies for non-native?) I've never even considered/known that guy was for males @AnnaLear. I guess we're on that now common list :)

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I dunno, I'm Russian. I learned that "guy" meant "man" back in the day. But let's not measure non-nativeness. I think it's sufficient to say that If English isn't your first language, it's possible that you may or may not know the finer points of common daily usage of anything in various English-speaking countries. :)

Comment: @JohnSaunders I myself almost downvoted the question because I thought that considering only he when using guys was so deprecated..

Comment: In other words, the question is no longer a question and the fact that I asked it is proof that I'm getting old? In fact, perhaps this would have been a question ten years ago, but recently, it's no longer an issue? That's fine. That's the sort of thing I wanted to find out. I just didn't realize I was so far out of date as to get downvotes. I was expecting, "no, don't bother, just get rid of salutations".

Comment: @JohnSaunders _"... and the fact that I asked it is proof that I'm getting old? ... "_ Yeah, somehow. Welcome to the club (warm welcoming by a even bit younger member ;-) ).

Comment: Why all the downvotes?  This seems like a well-considered question, complete with the background leading the op to ask it, and a clearly open mind to what others think?  As always, people can vote as they see fit, but I'm curious what about this question to the community would be viewed so negatively?

Comment: @AnnaLear: "guy" *does* mean "man", but as it happens, man is similarly ambiguous! You especially see this in older works, but stuff like "peace on earth, good will to men" is not just referring to males. English is crazy I tell you what.

Comment: @NathanTuggy English is all kinds of crazy. :) I'll restate my (tangential) point in its entirety one more time and then stop responding to nitpicks, though: it's possible for someone not familiar with English much to take the literal translation at face value.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: why would someone downvote because "considering only he when using guys" is deprecated? Did I leave the impression that *I* use the term "guys" to mean only males? This question was about whether I should edit the posts of people who use the term "guys".

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen: thanks for finding that. I agree this is effectively a dupe of that question, with it's 17 answers!

Comment: See also: [Any thoughts on how to react to gender-specific language?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176181/203389) - Meta Stack Exchange

Comment: @JohnSaunders Yes, I was really convinced that was how you used the word. sorry about that!

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: interesting. Could that be due to the word "guy" in French? Or am I just unclear in _any_ language?

Comment: I think it's because of `It still bothers me to see something like that.` that I understood you would mean it that way

Comment: I edit posts and make them gender neutral. TBH, I don't think any female or non-guy member will expect it from others to edit posts on her behalf. She should edit it herself like I do. Unless you assume that females members of this community don't have edit privs [now I am offended `:D` ], so just edit it if you feel it should be edited.

Comment: I have gotten the sense in past discussions on related topics that some members here don't see considerations of gender and language as a problem worth discussion. I hesitate to speak for anonymous voters, but I'd suggest that as one possibility to consider for the cause of downvotes here: "talking about this is a waste of time".

Comment: It isn't a waste of time. Ever since I joined SE, [I have seen it being discussed multiple times](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265538/2982225). Generally a post which starts with "hi guys" is of low quality. Very few (if any) well written posts contain this kind of language. If I see a good post with guys in it, will I feel offended? No. Will I edit it and make it gender-neutral? Yes. I will edit it because it will be "an improvement".

Comment: "Guys" isn't gender-specific, "gentleman" and "sirs" are. "Guys" doesn't annoy me, but it is pretty irritating when an OP posts something like "I appreciate all the help gentlemen!!" after I've helped them. But as others have said, almost anything that could involve gender-specific words should be edited out anyways. At the same time, silently editing out this stuff isn't helping to change the culture here that assumes everyone is male.

Comment: In order to keep my speech gender-neutral, I shall now refer to people as "asshole" (in the singular) and "assholes" (in the plural).

Answer (score 10):

I am personally okay with a colloquial and well-understood usage on Stack Exchange.

When someone says "guys," I know that they mean "people" in the general sense. **There is a battle over whether this language should be changed; we should not fight that battle here.**

In technicality, I prefer the pronoun "they." I'm not going to go into why; this isn't really the place for it. Do I wish everyone knew this and used 'they'? Kinda. But I also get that if somebody were to look at me, they would go "this person is male," and use a male pronoun. Most of the time, it's just not worth the uncomfortable moment and long explanation. Like right now, for instance. Similarly, the difference between "What are your guys' thoughts?" and "What are the community's thoughts?" is trivial.

Introducing this debate to the field of Stack Exchange is counter to the ultimate purpose of this site.

The linguistic battle over whether we should use gender-neutral language is a serious one, and it's a complex, multi-faceted issue. It's not as simple as "do or do not use." That being said, **we have to remember what we're here for: we're here to make the internet better by providing better resources for programmers.** Does fighting over the use of *trivial* gendered terminology help this cause? No, not really.

---

Don't get me wrong; this is an important issue, and I in no way wish to isolate or reject women on Stack Exchange. But let's all agree that "guys" is a colloquialism for "people," and leave it at that. If using this language changes elsewhere, it will change here, too. Stack Exchange Q&A isn't the place to fight it.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that, because you use "guys" in a generic manner, that everyone who says "guys" uses it in a generic manner.

Comment: @John In this case, you're right, I am making that assumption. I assume that people are good-hearted, and usually don't intend to isolate women, and I choose to read it that way. You can make a different choice if you'd like.

Comment: This is a world-wide web site. Are you assuming that people "don't intend to isolate women" all around the entire world? Are you unable to think of anyplace in the world where women are marginalized?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Just sticking this out there, can you point to an instance where a *woman* was offended at this usage?

Comment: @Undo: no, I can't, which was one of the purposes of my question. I was checking myself. It had occurred to me that this might no longer be a problem, though it used to be. I was looking for opinions on whether the problem still existed and whether I should do anything about it. And, BTW, this is also why I was explicitly asking women. The opinions of men are less important in this case.

Comment: @John I'm certain there are people here who intentionally or unconsciously marginalize women. Stack Exchange isn't the place to fight very, very minor usages that are colloquially understood to be gender-neutral, even if they're by text not.