# Call to help with editing: when an "RTFM" drop spilled the cup

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette, quality-improvement, behavior

I have spent some time going over the [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) and [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) tags (which are the areas I mostly spend my time in) to remove any references to "[RTFM](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/RTFM)", by replacing them with "RTM" and, as indicated under [How should we deal with RTFM comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23628/how-should-we-deal-with-rtfm-comments), there are better ways to advise people to read the manual.

For people who have some extra time on their hands: edit questions and/or answers that contain "RTFM" by removing the "F" or replace it with "Read the manual" (by accessing https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rtfm or by entering a tag name followed by "rtfm": `[tag_name] rtfm` in the **Search** input).

e.g.: `[javascript] rtfm`, or URL `https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]rtfm`.

I noticed that there are just under 2,000 of these when I linked to https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rtfm

I am willing to make my part in this but feel that it would take too much of my time to remove/modify them all by myself. 5-15 minutes here and there wouldn't take much for a bunch of us to clean this all up, or most of them. 
Like the community I "live" in, it's always a pleasant experience to "be" somewhere as I am sure you like that also; least I hope. Stack Overflow etc. is no different in certain respects. A community (should) pull together when something needs to be done.

I don't want or hope to not pass off as a martyr. I just feel that it would be a better place for everyone to interact in a sane and peaceful environment by not provoking people in telling them to "RTFM".

Links to check for "RTFM" under [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) and [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) tags:

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+rtfm
- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[mysql]+rtfm

The `php` one still contains a few "RTFM"'s, only because those contain what MailChimp used to be have that contained valid URL's at the time; they are 404's now.

Comment: This question seems to have a lot of unnecessary content and could do with being considerably shortened.

Comment: Maybe i'm mis-understanding your point... (question kinda jumps around a bit imo) Are you suggesting we go around replacing RTFM with RTM? seems like instead those comments should be removed and replaced with downvotes on the questions.

Comment: I really do not see a need to go back and edit stuff that is already done.  We could try and blacklist the comments like we do for let me google that for you comments going forward.

Comment: @KevinB Only suggesting, not "telling". I feel that those "RTFM"'s should be removed, I don't see the harm or being "off-topic" in simply asking people to remove/edit those, IMHO, what's wrong with that? Something that can be done in free time, I took the initiative to do away with those in the php/mysql section.

Comment: @NathanOliver well I do and there are Q&A's about this as well as "it" being the "RTFM"s being non-constructive. I don't see why I should be commenting here to defend my question. Ask any moderator and they'll tell you the same thing: "Non-constructive, flag it".

Comment: @Fred-ii- Right.. but... It feels like the wrong battle to be having. We have a tide of new (and returning!) users who repeatedly ask poorly researched questions. Downvotes on said questions are the only tool we have to help fight back said tide because it affects the rate at which said users can ask questions, thus forcing them to wait, and possibly do more research. Removing comments made previously on the other hand won't have much impact.

Comment: @MartinSmith You may be right, and I may shorten it down later, unless you have some suggestions as to what you feel doesn't belong.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm not saying they aren't constructive.  What I am saying as this task is just so huge that instead of trying to fix the stuff already posted we just blacklist the comments going forward and then we do not have to deal with it.

Comment: @KevinB It isn't a battle per se, it's just a matter of taking control and the initiative; I don't see what's wrong with that. People spend their time on meta to look over posts, and when they feel are bad, they show a negative response to it. I knew that was going to happen and TBH; it doesn't affect me one bit. I posted what I thought was a valid post and I stand by it.

Comment: If people have time to post negative responses to a valid post, then they have time to get rid of the "RTFM"'s. I honestly can't see why my post is getting negative reviews.

Comment: I'm not saying your post is invalid... or anything like that. And i'm not saying you should stop. What i am saying is... there's more productive things you could be doing. There's more productive ways to prevent RTFM from appearing. and replacing RTFM with RTM doesn't make it less offensive.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, there are better ways and that is outlined in my post. If I have to get rid of all the "RTFM"'s in the entire section of Stack myself, then I will. It will take me some time, but believe me.. I will. What is 5-10 mins. of someone's time? Community support isn't what I expected here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think if you edited down your post to be a lot more concise and specific regarding your recommendations you might get a better response. I honestly had a hard time following what you were saying.

Comment: @KevinB *"and replacing RTFM with RTM doesn't make it less offensive"* - That's where I think you're wrong. You know what the "F" stands for, we all do. "RTM" means "Read The Manual" as opposed to the "F" version. Come on.... and to think that we stand to see more of those in comments/answers, shouldnt' be upvoted as some do, they just make matters worse.

Comment: @NathanArthur I have no problem to remove stuff that the community feels isn't needed. If you have any suggestions as to what doesn't belong, do let me know, I'm not obtuse ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Decide what you want to communicate, and then delete all the words that don't say that. I can't do that for you. One suggestion, nonetheless: I had trouble following the story (?) you started the post with. That story could probably have been shortened to one paragraph.

Comment: so, just under 2000 questions that failed to be deleted because someone answered instead of downvoting.

Comment: @KevinB I don't understand what you're saying. *"That failed to be deleted'* - "what" failed to be deleted? Sorry but I'm not following.

Comment: The useless, poorly researched low quality questions failed to be deleted. mostly due to having an upvoted answer stating RTFM. Many others do end up closed or deleted, as they should.

Comment: Also... `?q=rtfm+is%3Aanswer` would probably be a better search query to use, far less false positives.

Comment: @KevinB Sure, but what about "questions"? That criteria would omit questions.

Comment: What's wrong with a question using RTFM?

Comment: @KevinB It still promotes "RTFM" where answers will most likely quote their *"I should have RTFM"*.

Comment: in the time that some may have spent on my question and bashing it, they could have easily modified 10 questions by now, just as I have.

Comment: Or.. even rolled back such useless edits.

Comment: @KevinB I won't roll them back; I don't have to. I felt I did a good thing here. If you want to keep supporting those, then we're obviously not seeing eye to eye here.

Comment: I'd rather see said answers/questions deleted.

Comment: @Fred-ii- In the time that you spent writing a 500 word question that only actually says 2 sentences worth of content, you could have easily flagged dozens of inappropriate comments.  In the time that you've spent complaining about people telling you that your question isn't understandable, you could have re-written your question to one that *is* understandable.  Complaining about how people aren't taking the time to understand your poorly written question, while also refusing to take the time to write it clearly, is rather hypocritical.

Comment: @Servy I do that "here and there". I don't spend my entire time trying to do a clean up. I'm not "complaining" I am "stating". If people are "with" RTFM's, then you're all against me.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well it sure comes off as complaining from my point of view.

Comment: So, keep those RTFM's coming, I'll flag them when I see them.

Comment: @Servy It wasn't intended that way, believe me.

Comment: @Servy *"you could have easily flagged dozens of inappropriate comments"* - I have. Plus, it's not only comments, it's questions and answers containing those. I'll keep on flagging them **"when"** I see them. I'm just wondering if I flag questions/answers as such, that they most likely will be declined. If I get too many declined flags, then I'll lose that privilege. So, here I am holding a double-edged sword.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don't see anyone here defending the use of RTFM. For my part, I actually upvoted your question. Saying we're all "'with' RTFM's" is not fair. Profit from feedback and your cause will be benefited.

Comment: @NathanArthur You're right; me neither. Some of them were probably the ones upvoting the answers/comments. As I said to someone else earlier; I'll just keep flagging those comments "when" I see them. After a while, I take it that if they get too many flags against them, that moderation goes into effect. Hey... I wasn't always a "prince" and I've been told by moderators to "cool it", and I have. I see myself as being a good contributor to "the community" and I've nothing to feel sorry about or my behaviour. +1 btw. and thanks.

Comment: I downvoted because I'm not really bothered either way about the RTFM issue (use it, don't use it, remove it from every post, add it to every post, couldn't care less, my skin's thick enough not to be concerned about whether someone's using the F word or not on the internet), but you could've got that point across in about two paragraphs rather than the rambling nature of this post as it is now. You stole my time, I won't get that back :) That and the quotes when nothing's being quoted. That really "bugs" me...

Comment: The only person who "stole your time" is you @Clive. You could've stopped reading at any point.

Comment: It was tongue in cheek @Jay. The reasons for the downvote obviously stand separately.

Comment: FYI: I have now moved on. Thanks to all for your contributions.

Comment: Ah - cool @Clive. Hard to know in text sometimes.

Comment: Yeah it gets me into trouble more often than I'd care to admit @Jay. But I'm British, sarcasm is my bread and butter, I shall not let it die ;)

Comment: It's always good to remove rude comments. However, I'd like to raise my hand in defense of "RTFM" in general. "RTFM" is a tradition. The same mindset (not necessarily the same person) that declares war on "RTFM" will go on to to  war on [guys](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283115/should-we-be-using-gendered-terminology-to-address-the-general-population) and then on to [preferred pronouns](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265299/editing-out-gender-pronouns-in-answers). Going all the way  down that PC road will lose us a lot of members. Please let us not start.

Comment: Attempting to modify an industry standard is likely to fail.

Comment: I consider RTFM no better than LMGTFY, which we currently disallow. Neither is a constructive when posted as a comment or part of an answer, **regardless** of the "F" in "RTFM". It's not an issue of profanity, it's an issue of posting dismissive and non-constructive noise. If you have a link to the documentation you wish to share, *share it*. "Have you read [relevant link to documentation]" is massively more useful than the comment that triggered this discussion, which was somebody repeatedly posting  `[RTFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM)` as a comment below questions from new users.

Comment: TBH, it's an annoying waste of typing.  Such questions don't deserve 4/6 keypresses, (or, for that matter, anyone to provide links).  Just downvote and move on - one click and you're done with it.

Comment: I'm mystified by the deletion of my comment recommending that the OP "GAFL". In case the self-proclaimed arbiters of moral purity missed it, IT WAS A JOKE. What is this, Sunday School?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's a lot to unpack here, but I think I see where this started and where you're trying to go with it.

An experienced member of the site decided that the best way to combat low quality questions was to copy and paste the same insulting comment telling people to "RTFM" across many questions. This was flagged by you and others, and moderators sent a message to them that we did not think these comments were helpful or constructive. They read that message and dramatically increased the rate at which they were posting this comment, adding more direct insults to users along with it. Over 50 of these comments were deleted before we decided to suspend their account to get them to stop.

Many of the questions these comments were posted on were awful, and pointing the asker to reference material could possibly help them. However, these comments simply told someone to "RTFM" without any link to said manual and were left to insult the poster. Insults are never an appropriate response to someone posting a poorly-formulated question.

The problem isn't so much "RTFM" as a phrase (although it's not very friendly), it's the overall rudeness in these comments. Simply replacing "RTFM" with "RTM" doesn't necessarily solve the problem. For example, telling someone:

> Read the manual: [link]

still comes off as a little harsh and doesn't provide great direction. Compare that with:

> The function you want here is blarg(), and it is documented here: [link]

If your goal is to replace RTFM entries in answers with RTM, that by itself might not do much to improve tone. Also, answers tend not to be the place where this is a problem, comments are where people go to use RTFM as an insult. Answers that include "RTFM" as a phrase might be doing it with a little more humor, and might have provided enough context to take the edge off. I'd focus first on the cases where this really was intended in an insulting manner.

For comments, if you see RTFM being used to insult or demean someone, please feel free to flag those for our attention.

Comment: Yes Brad, you are right about all this and only "you" and other moderators know where "my" RTFM drop filled the glass and TBH, I had quite enough of this behaviour and as to the root of it all started with what people thought as being "cool" or what not. I'm doing what I think/thought was best to clean this whole mess up. Instead, I received an opposite reaction to an action I found to be fit. As you can tell, I did not mention any names here, which goes back to the beginning of my comment. If you feel that I should stop editing questions/answers about my modifications, please tell me now.

Comment: Well Brad, I'll just stop editing Q&A's then and just flag comments containing those as well as any supportive comments "supporting" them stating something like: *"+1 on that comment/answer"*. Thanks for your well-written answer and understanding what the real problem was. I take it that my question now in light of what I wrote here, would kind of be "null and void". Yet [the edit that Martin did](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/348914/2) with his "TLDR", made it as such; "null and void". Oh well, *"c'est la vie!"*

Comment: There is something I'd like you to answer (for me) though Brad; by leaving those "RTFM"'s in existing Q&A's, aren't we (sort of) allowing that term (and behaviour) to be introduced in (future) comments? People see those and of course are (probably) prone to use that term and for future posts; this being for questions/answers/comments. [Servy said it was hypocritical on my part](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348914/when-an-rtfm-drop-spilled-the-cup?noredirect=1#comment471624_348914), I'd say by keeping those intact and allowing those for the future, is hypocritical in its own right.