# If a user is pointlessly mass-editing questions and answers, should I report them, if so how?

Tags: discussion

Question title is pretty self-explanatory, but to explain even further.

A bunch of edits appeared in my inbox all due to a single user who has been "pointlessly" editing questions. We are talking things such as:

Editing `For example:` to `For example,`

which I don't believe is a justified edit.

Obviously it's not a big deal, but it is rather irritating when users trawl through questions and answers which are years old making tiny, minor edits to things in order to bag themselves some reputation.

Should I report this spammy / borderline vandalism behaviour, i.e., is it against SO rules or not really? If so, how?

Comment: Just so you know, after 2k no one gets any reputation from editing. Also the [edit did cater to all the issues in the post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24392000/revisions).

Comment: I think rollback should indeed be flagged for moderator attention - change put back wrong formatting for code and thank you notes...

Comment: "spammy / borderline vandalism" Spammy how? Quantity alone doesn't make spam. There's no self-promotion, no rep gain. And as for vandalism -- the post Bhargav Rao linked was definitely improved (if slightly) by the edits. Please consider at least removing the "thanks..." and taking the hints on proper code-block formatting.

Comment: As for Peter Mortensen's changes I'd flag for moderator attention if there would be "give thanks to a user for awesome edits" (I like https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/348794/revisions change to my post for example, as well as change linked by Bhargav Rao).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov same problem with rollback [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24392248/revisions)...

Comment: Please don't ever use the rollback function again. It is very obvious that your idea of a good edit is very different from the community's idea of a good edit. If anyone's behavior is in question here, it is yours.

Answer (score 15):

Let's start with the brutal reality of it:  [the network encourages you to make edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120583/175248).  Of the kinds of edits you should do are:

- Fixing spelling
- Fixing/reuploading image
- Improving clarity in a phrase

...and **the edits you show us do that.** So I wouldn't think for a minute that the behavior is "spammy" or "inappropriate".

Note that edits which don't do any of that sort of thing *are* not wanted and can be made eligible to be rolled back.  This includes things like:

- Putting words in the OP's mouth
- Changing the question
- Embedding their *own* question into another question

Any of the above should definitely be flagged for moderator attention; just do so on the post in question, include a link to the edit history and explain why this is a problem.

You would be well served to remember that we gain the privilege to edit, not because we're trying to be rude or anything like that, but because we want to ensure that the content on this site is actually clear and useful to others in the future.  I can't fault the editor for making the edits they did, since they're decent at keeping readability at a maximum.

(Also, they don't gain rep for this (because this specific person is above 2K rep), so they're *literally* doing this for free.)

Answer (score -5):

Flag the post being edited for moderator attention and explain your concerns.

Comment: Just curious, what will/should a moderator do in this situation if they see this edit flag?

Comment: @aug sometimes people go on editing spree based on some idea that are not really supported at the moment (i.e. one could go and spell-check all "thank in advanced" comments instead of removing + fixing whole post). Moderator can see such edits and notify or even suspend user till that sorted out. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348923/477420 for an example). (I don't think any action is needed in this particular case, but in general flagging with detailed explanation is good route to deal with edits you have concern with but uncomfortable to point out directly)

Comment: @aug sometimes people take offense to reasonable actions, in which case they can flag such actions and be told by a moderator that those actions are perfectly reasonable.